# Need a formula to check the first x amount of characters if numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a formula to check if the first 7 characters in the cell are numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more rigorous (see my comment to the previous poster's solution) to check each character for numericalness on an individual basis, e.g.:

`=COUNT(0+MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},1))=7`

Regards

Comment: See my second comment to the first response.

Answer (score 2):

> =ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,7)*1)

Assume you are putting data in A1

Comment: This will report that *1.23456abcd* is **TRUE** although the dot is not a number!

Comment: concept problem.. dot is not a number but `1.23456` is a number, let say you can draw a square with `1.23456`cm, but you can't draw `.` square

Comment: I'm quite surprised that this answer has received 3 'useful' votes, as it really is not a very rigorous one. Apart from the example given by Gary's Student, any string which can be interpreted by Excel as a valid date string, a valid time string or scientific notation will cause this construction to give incorrect results. For example, given the appropriate language/date settings (i.e. English, UK Date System), the following string in A1 - MARCH1234 - will return TRUE. As will 1234E1234 and 12:34 ABC, to name just two more.

Comment: @XORLX  It is a *semantic* difference:  Do the first 7 characters *(as a whole)* represent a number? v.s. Are **each** of the first 7 characters a numeral??

Comment: I might disagree with your statement there of what "represents a number". In Excel, as I have shown, that's a very broad definition indeed. I cannot imagine a situation in which somebody would wish for "MARCH1234" to meet either of your definitions.

Comment: To coin a phrase...."I agree with XOR LX" - using this formula I get TRUE with **2E1** and **1oct**, they don't even have 7 characters.....